# typescript error in redis - on event

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

```
import * as redis from 'redis'
import config from '../../config/config'
const client = redis.createClient(config.redis.port, host, config.redis.options);
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('redis is ready.')
});
```

getting below error in typescript

[ts] Property 'on' does not exist on type '{ address: any; connection_options: { [x: string]: any; }; connection_id: number; connected: bool...'. any

Comment: Installed `@types/redis`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, have you installed the type module for the redis module? I highly recommend doing that as it helps TypeScript compiler and potentially your IDE to know what commands and interfaces are available in the redis module. To do so:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/redis
```

Second, try adding the `.on('error', console.error)` to see if your client is emitting any meaningful connection errors. There could be a problem with you client credentials, which fails the connections.

Lastly, you can completely skip the `.on('ready', ...)` event handler as it's not necessary. The redis module queues all the commands sent before the connection is established, and will automatically send them once it's successfully connected. You can just start testing the client with simple `set` and `get` commands.

Comment: I am trying the same but facing following issue,
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: net.isIP is not a function
TypeError: net.isIP is not a function.

Comment: @Tejal Can you provide the context? Including the code that causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Everything seemed fine, redis typings were installed (actually already provided by the redis package).

However, I simply forgot to install the nodejs types... Without these typing, typescript isn't aware of, i.a, the EventEmitter.

Try installing:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```